# Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте!

Можно на этом ресурсе выложить изложение для проверки грамотности? Это не школьное задание, это для саморазвития. Просто репетитор дорого стоит.)))
Если нельзя, прошу модератора удалить это сообщение.

Я печатал в текстовом редакторе, чтобы не подчеркивались ошибки, проверил, теперь хочу, чтобы знающие люди проверили!

```
Как то весной, в знойный вечер, на Патриарших прудах появились два гражданина. Один из них маленького роста, полноват. Второй - рыжеватый, широкоплечий, в клетчетой кепке - был в черных туфлях и белых штанах.
Первого званли Михаил Александрович Берлиоз, председатель МАССОЛИТ, и редактор художественного журнала, а молодой товарищь - Иван Николаевич Понырев, известный под именем Бездомный
Укрывшись в тени огромных лип, писатели первым делом кинулись к будочку "Пиво и вода".
Во всей аллее небыло ни одного человека. Странность этого пугающего, весеннего вечера подчеркивалась, тем, что ни один человек, в этот жаркий час,
не пришел посидеть на скамейки, укутанных тенью зеленеющих лип.
-Дайте миниральную воду, - спрсил Берлиоз
-Нету, - обиженно ответила продавщица
-Пиво есть? - спросил Бездомный.
-Нету, - проговорила продовщица.
-А что есть?
-Теплая абирокосовая.
-Ну, давайте, давайте, давайте!
После опустошения стаканов, поэты, икая, расплатились и уселись на скамейку в направлении пруда.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Как-то** весной, в знойный вечер, на Патриарших прудах появились два гражданина. Один из них маленького роста, полноват. Второй - рыжеватый, широкоплечий, в клетч**а**той кепке - был в черных туфлях и белых штанах. Первого звали Михаил Александрович Берлиоз, это председатель МАССОЛИТ**а** и редактор художественного журнала, а молодой **товарищ** - Иван Николаевич Понырев, известный под именем Бездомный. Укрывшись в тени огромных лип, писатели первым делом кинулись к будочк**е** "Пиво и вода". Во всей аллее **не было** ни одного человека. Странность этого пугающего весеннего вечера подчеркивалась тем, что ни один человек в этот жаркий час не пришел посидеть на скамейк**е**, укутанн**ой** тенью зеленеющих лип.

-Дайте мин**е**ральную воду, - **попро**сил Берлиоз.

-Нету, - обиженно ответила продавщица .

-Пиво есть? - спросил Бездомный.

-Нету, - проговорила прод**а**вщица.

-А что есть?

-Теплая **абрикосовая**.

-Ну, давайте, давайте, давайте!

После опустошения стаканов поэты, икая, расплатились и уселись на скамейку **около** пруда.

Comment: Ещё: "Пиво и воды", а не "Пиво и вода" - в тексте так.
Вместо "около пруда" можно "лицом к пруду", но не в направлении пруда.

Comment: И лучше не  "после опустошения стаканов", а "опустошив стаканы".